# Add active menu item class to menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, menu

I am trying to generate a current menu item active class on ahref tags in a menu

```
var word = $('#lgaa-section').attr("class") 
// generates string e.g 'Munster Hurling'


// This code doesn't work
$('.second-menu-wrap a:contains(word)').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == word;
}).addClass('active');


// This code works when I put an actual known string in

$('.second-menu-wrap a:contains(Munster Hurling)').filter(function() {
 return $(this).text() == 'Munster Hurling';
}).addClass('active');
```

// assistance would be appreciated

*UPDATE I got this to work thanks to Roosters suggestion to change the contains selector to ('+$word+') I also had to declare the variabe using the jquery symbol $

Here is the working code

```
$word = $('#lgaa-section').attr("class")

$('.second-menu-wrap a:contains('+$word+')').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == $word;
}).addClass('current-menu-item');
```

Comment: Please explain the results you are experiencing vs. what is expected.  It is unclear what you're trying to do and what isn't working.  The more detail, the more likely someone will be able to help you.

Comment: $('.second-menu-wrap a:contains('+word+')') as the selector work?